# import a method from a class into another class JS

Tags: javascript, class

I'm still beginner in JS and I feel like I'm often dealing with some basic stuffs out here.. I want to retrieve/import a method from a class A into class B (using modules). Also, I don't know if my code is well built so I'm open for all suggestions and advices.

**Here's class 1 (A)**

```
    export default class A {
       constructor() {
        this.zone = document.getElementById('#zone');
        this.array = [];
        this.init();
    }
    
    init() {
        //code
    }


    methodToImport(id) {
        let DOM = `<h1>HTML Content</h1>`
        this.zone.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', DOM);
        this.array.push(new B(this.zone.lastElementChild));
    }
```

**and here's class 2 (B)**

```
    import A from "./A.js";
    class B {
      constructor(element) {
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
            // here I want to retrieve the array duly wholy fillen with instances of class A 
            console.log(A.array);
    }
    }
```

I really wish you could help, thank you guys !

Comment: You are creating a circular dependency by importing A in B and again B in A

Comment: There is no `A.array`. `array` is a property of an instance, not the class itself.

Comment: in class B let a = new A();

Answer (score 0):

you can create an object of class A in class B and use it.

```
    class A {
            constructor() {
            this.zone = document.getElementById('#zone');
            this.array = [1,2,3,4];
            }
    }

    class B {
        constructor(element) {
        this.a = new A;
        }
    }

    b = new B
    console.log(b.a.array);
```